# How to ignore undefined blocks dimming?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I would like IntelliSense to show blocks of code which are under '1' defined macros as active, and to dim (show inactive) blocks which are under '0' defined macros. The blocks of code which are under undefined macros should be ignored (showed as active). Is that possible?

`C_Cpp.dimInactiveRegions: true`

Current behavior:

```
#define SOME_DEFINED_MACRO         1

#if (SOME_DEFINED_MACRO == 1)

    foo(); //active code

#else

    bar(); //inactive (dimmed) code
  
#endif

#if (SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO == 2)

    fizz(); //inactive (dimmed) code
 
#elif (SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO == 10)

    buzz(); //inactive (dimmed) code

#endif
```

Desired behavior:

```
#define SOME_DEFINED_MACRO         1

#if (SOME_DEFINED_MACRO == 1)

    foo(); //active code

#else

    bar(); //inactive (dimmed) code as far as SOME_DEFINED_MACRO is defined but equals 1
  
#endif

#if (SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO == 2)

    fizz(); //active code as far as SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO is undefined, so ignore dimming
 
#elif (SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO == 10)

    buzz(); //active code as far as SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO is undefined, so ignore dimming

#endif
```

Comment: do you want intellisense to show those blocks as active even though they're inactive or do you want the blocks to actually be active?

Comment: That's how C++ is supposed to work. If a macro is undefined, using it in a condition will equate its value with zero.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `#if !defined(SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO) || (SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO == 2)`? But then note that those section will be built and executed when `SOME_UNDEFINED_MACRO` is undefined.

Comment: One file is being compiled for different SoC cores. Some blocks are active for one core, some blocks are active for other ones. I would like to see active all of them, regardless the core. I would like to see them active even though they are actually inactive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us about the underlying and actual problem you need to solve.

Comment: Which IDE? AFAIK my visual studio 2022 behaves like this and it does gray out the correct pieces of code (depending on the active project)

Comment: C++ standard requires undefined macros to be treated as 0, so I would be surprised if it was configurable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, just wondering if there is a chance